# CanCan accessibly_by returns different responses in spec and controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cancan, rolify

I am trying to test the user authentication for the `Farm` model, in this case for the `:user` role which has **read** access to all farms when being logged-in (as the guest user aka. anonymous has too).

```
# /models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # Create guest user aka. anonymous (not logged in) when user is nil.
    user ||= User.new

    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else # guest user aka. anonymous
      can :read, :all
      # logged in user
      if user.has_role? :user
        can :create, Farm
        can :manage, Farm, :user_id => user.id
      end
    end

  end
end
```

...

```
# /controllers/api/v1/farms_controller.rb
class Api::V1::FarmsController < ActionController::Base

    load_and_authorize_resource
    rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
        redirect_to farms_path, alert: exception.message
    end
    respond_to :json

    def index
        # Next line might be redundant refering to the CanCan wiki. See below..
        @farms = Farm.accessible_by(current_ability, :read)
        respond_with(@farms)
    end
end
```

...

```
# /spec/api/v1/farm_spec.rb
require "spec_helper"

describe "/api/v1/farms" do
    let(:user) { create(:user) } # lets call this user1 in the discussion
    let(:token) { user.authentication_token }

    before do
        user.add_role :user
        create(:farm, user: user, name: "Testfarm")
        create(:farm, name: "Access denied")
        @ability = Ability.new(user)
    end

    context "farms viewable by this logged-in user" do
        let(:url) { "/api/v1/farms" }
        it "json" do
            get "#{url}.json"

            farms_json = Farm.accessible_by(@ability, :read).to_json

            assert last_response.ok?
            last_response.body.should eql(farms_json)
            last_response.status.should eql(200)

            farms = JSON.parse(last_response.body)

            farms.any? do |farm|
                farm["name"] == "Testfarm"
            end.should be_true

            farms.any? do |farm|
                farm["name"] == "Access denied"
            end.should be_true

        end
    end
end
```

## The problem

When I inspect `farms_json` I can see it contains **only** the `Testfarm`. When I inspect the `last_response` I can see it contains **both** the `Testfarm` **and** `Access denied`. This is strange since I use the same `accessible_by` method both in the spec and the `index` action. The setup I use is described in the wiki of the CanCan gem entitled [Fetching Records](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records).

## The useless workaround

When I add the user `user` to the farm `Access denied`, such as ...

```
create(:farm, user: user, name: "Access denied")
```

... then the test succeeds.

## The questions

1. Why is the "Access denied" farm **not** returned although it can be read by any user (including guest users)?
2. Does `get "#{url}.json"` actually consider the status of the user? Is this all done by `load_and_authorize_resource` in the `FarmsController`?
3. The [wiki mentions](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records) that `@farms = Farm.accessible_by(current_ability, :read)` can be left out since "this is done automatically by `load_resource` for the index action". Does this apply to my situation?

## Experiments

I created another user "user2" and another farm "My little farm". I linked those to each other. This way the database in the example contains three farms alltogether:

- Farm "Testfarm" associated to user1
- Farm "Access denied" associated to no user
- Farm "My little farm" associated to user2.

When I run `Farm.accessible_by(Ability.new(user1), :read)` I still only receive "Testfarm".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question consists of multiple parts. I hope this clarifies the setup to everyone else who deals with a similar configuration.

## 1. Ability Precedence

First of all please mind that the [order of ability rules does matter as described in Ability Precedence](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ability-Precedence). After realizing this fact I came up with an updated set of ability rules.

```
# /models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # Create guest user aka. anonymous (not logged-in) when user is nil.
    user ||= User.new

    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
      # logged in user
      if user.has_role? :user
        can :manage, Farm, :user_id => user.id
        can :create, Farm
      end
       # guest user aka. anonymous
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

## 2. FarmsContoller

Keep it simple in the index action. `load_and_authorize_resource` is your friend.

```
# /controllers/api/v1/farms_controller.rb
class Api::V1::FarmsController < ActionController::Base

    load_and_authorize_resource
    rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
        redirect_to farms_path, alert: exception.message
    end
    respond_to :json

    def index
        respond_with(@farms)
    end
end
```

## 3. Get request with authentication token

Do not forget to pass the token when you request data from the farms controller.

```
# # /spec/api/v1/farm_spec.rb
get "#{url}.json", auth_token: :token
```

The token must be added in the User model as follows.

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :ensure_authentication_token
```

And the name of the method can be configured in the initializer of Devise.

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.token_authentication_key = :auth_token
```